# Mapping sharepoint 2013 Network drive to Mac

Tags: macos, sharepoint, network-drive

I'm trying to map a network drive of sharepoint 2013 online to my Mac os X. I'm following this link -  http://www.usciences.edu/it/helpdesk/forstudents/MacDriveMapping.shtml  , url of my network drive is -  https://moonraftinnovationlabs-public.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage/

I have a username and pwd for it

Whenever I click on connect it says - "problem connecting to the drive. Contact your system administrator for more information"

Comment: How is this to do with programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X doesn't (directly) support MS SharePoint. The link you gave describes how to map a folder shared over the SMB protocol, not SharePoint (although the same basic process would also work for the AFP, WebDAV, or NFS protocols). If you need to access SharePoint from OS X, you need to use a browser (Safari and Firefox are supported), or Microsoft Office for Mac (see [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/11/13/sharepoint-2010-on-a-mac-with-office-for-mac-2011.aspx)). In any case, you won't be able to access it from the Finder, or "map" it in the sense you're looking for.

Comment: So I cant map just this url directly to my network drive, why It does not behave like a normal URL?

Comment: A URL is just a standardized format for describing how to reach a network resource; if the client software you're using (the Finder in this case) doesn't support the protocol the resource is being served over, it's not going to work.

Comment: If you have Office 2011 installed, run Microsoft Document Connection and you can add SharePoint sites through that.It will allow you to edit files with your desired text editor and won't require SP Designer.

Answer (score 3):

I have connected to Sharepoint folders in OSX using HTTPS. It's buggy and slow though. In finder I go to "Go" and select "Connect to server." Then I enter the URL of the folder in the sharepoint site. An example:

```
https://intranet.BLAHBLAH.edu/departments/BLAH/Technology/Shared%20Docs
```

However as commenter wilsjd pointed out, it has very limited functionality. I found I could download but not save/upload. The officially supported "solution" is Microsoft Document Connection, which allows uploads but in a very inefficient and clunky manner.

Comment: Beware if you do this, you won't be able to edit many documents (like Office documents for example).